# Pandas dynamic column creation

Tags: pandas

I am attempting to dynamically create a new column based on the values of another column.
Say I have the following dataframe

A|B
11|1
22|0
33|1
44|1
55|0

I want to create a new column.
If the value of column B is 1, insert 'Y' else insert 'N'.
The resulting dataframe should looks like so:

A|B|C
11|1|Y
22|0|N
33|1|Y
44|1|Y
55|0|N

I could do this by iterating through the column values,

```
for i in dataframe['B'].values:
    if i==1:
        add Y to Series
    else:
        add N to Series

dataframe['C'] = Series
```

However I am afraid this will severely reduce performance especially since my dataset contains 500,000+ rows.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid chained indexing by using `loc`. There are some subtleties with [returning a view versus a copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) in pandas that are related to `numpy`

```
df['C'] = 'N'
df.loc[df.B == 1, 'C'] = 'Y'
```

Comment: would it be possible to perform 2 comparisons but on a different dataframe? `df.loc[df2.B == 1 and df.A == df2.B, 'C'] = 'Y'`?

Comment: Yep. Only you have to use `&` instead of `and`, like this: `df.loc[(df2.B == 1) & (df.A == df2.B), 'C'] = 'Y'`. The parentheses are necessary because the `&` operator has higher precedence than `==`. Also, I believe `df` and `df2` must have the same indices for the fancy indexing to work.

Comment: great! my solution used merges though. The indices were against me on that one

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['C'] = 'N'
df['C'][df['B']==1] = 'Y'
```

should be faster.

Comment: worked like a charm! I just had to switch 1 to '1'. Thanks a lot!